Replicating complex MySQL/MariaDB query with multiple joins in Laravel DB Builder
I have a query with multiple joins. Most joins are a 1 to 1 but two are 1 to man. My sql query returns results as expected with data from the 1 to many joins flattened into a single value.  The two 1 to many joins are excuses and travel Here's my query:
select 
    a.Lastn,
    c.name, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(f.type,',',f.description) as Excuses, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(i.start,',', i.end,',', i.destination) as Travel 
from 
    jurors as a left join        
    pool_lkp as b on a.id = b.j_id left join 
    pools as c on b.p_id = c.id left join 
    accommodations as d on a.id = d.juror_id left join 
    employment as e on a.id = e.juror_id left join 
    excuses as f on a.id = f.juror_id left join 
    new_address as g on a.id = g.juror_id left join 
    spouse as h on a.id = h.juror_id left join 
    travel as i on a.id = i.juror_id 
where 
    c.id = 1 
group by 
    a.id 

I attempted to recreate this in Laravel using the DB Query builder.  The data from the 1 to many joins repeats several times. I suspect it is because of the two 1 to many joins would return multiple rows for a single record where that row has values in the two 1 to many tables.
Here's my attempt at replicating my query using the Laravel DB builder.
$results = DB::table('jurors')
    ->leftJoin('pool_lkp','jurors.id','=','pool_lkp.j_id')
    ->leftJoin('pools','pool_lkp.p_id','=','pools.id')
    ->leftJoin('accommodations','jurors.id','=','accommodations.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('employment','jurors.id','=','employment.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('excuses','jurors.id','=','excuses.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('new_address','jurors.id','=','new_address.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('spouse','jurors.id','=','spouse.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('travel','jurors.id','=','travel.juror_id')
    ->select(
        'jurors.id as jurorId',
        'jurors.*',
        'pools.*',
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(excuses.type,',',excuses.description) as Excuses"),
        DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(travel.start,',', travel.end,',', travel.destination) as Travel")
    )
    ->where('pools.id','=',$request->segment(3))
    ->groupBy('jurors.id')
    ->get();

I expected to see the data for the 1 to many tables flattened into a string in Excuses and Travel within my returned results. I see the flattened strings in the results returned for the Laravel DB builder query but the strings repeat several times.
Is there a bug in Laravel's DB Builder?

I dont think so  GROUP_CONCAT on 1-M will work this way

@AbdullaNilam it absolutely does

I mean in Laravel Query.

GROUP_CONCAT in Laravel Query concatenates the data into a string as expected but that string repeats once for each value in the 1 to many tables.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300140

can you give an example of what you receive vs what you want? Are you sure you are running both queries on the same connection?

@krisgjika the group concat values repeat over and over. With MariaDB you can add a limit to GROUP CONCAT and say LIMIT 1 so there are no redundant strings. MySQL doesn't have this feature.

so use MariaDB or better yet handle this application side? Not sure what the question is anymore

From the experience of once using mysql locally and maria on production I can tell you MariaDB is not the same thing as MySql, they have slight differences that often lead to production only bugs.

MariaDB is a MySQL with extra features. So yes they are not the same.

the query you show will absolutely repeat excuses if there are multiple travel in the group and vice versa.   so this isn't a laravel vs raw query difference, something else is making you see different data.  do verify the exact sql laravel is producing.  that said, usually this problem is dealt with by putting all or all but one of the 1 to many joins in a subquery, or just doing group_concat(distinct ...)

some sample data demonstrating the problem would make this much easier to talk about (and a minimal query demonstrating the problem, presumably all the other joins aren't an issue)

@ysth you're correct. GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  ) is the answer I needed. Also I had to switch from MySQL to MariaDB as MySQL doesn't support GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ).

@b_dubb mysql absolutely does support distinct with group_concat, for a very long time: https://dbfiddle.uk/QeQ2Szz7   it doesn't for json_arrayagg yet, but group_concat has it

@ysth https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300088/limit-the-number-of-rows-in-group-by-and-group-concat-with-order/300140#300140

yes, mysql does not have limit in group_concat.  it does have distinct, and order by.  it may never have support for limit; that's really better addressed by using a subquery.

@ysth example? If your sub query works better than group_concat(distinct ) I'll accept your answer

My guess because Your queries differ?
In Raw SQL You do: SELECT FROM pool and in Laravel You do: SELECT FROM jurors

That's a good catch. I'm going to say I tried the query both ways but I'm going to try that change again and see if it affects the flattened strings for the 1 to many relationships.

So I basically transposed juror and pools and updated the rest of the joins to reflect the change. The original query and the modified query return the same result set as the query I posted.  So I don't think you're answer is actually an answer.

Its hard to debug without knowing which tables are one to many. But still, Your select differs :). You are selecting different things, try selecting jurors.Lastn, pool.name and Your GROUP_CONCAT stuff

excuses and travel are the 1 to many tables

I think the answer to my question is you have to use MariaDB which supports LIMIT within the GROUP_CONCAT() to prevent repeated GROUP_CONCAT() values.
EDIT: Actually what worked for me was GROUP_CONCAT(LIMIT cols);
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300140

Different queries tend to give different results. You can call the toSql() or toRawSql() method on a query builder object to make sure your query is looking the way you expect it to.
Other than that, for large queries like this you can make the Builder look very similar to SQL.
$query = DB::query()
    ->select([
        'a.name', 
        'c.Lastn', 
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(f.type, ",", f.description) AS Excuses'), 
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(i.start, ",", i.end, ",", i.destination) AS Travel') 
    ])
    ->from('pools', 'a')
    ->leftJoin('pool_lkp AS b', 'a.id', 'b.p_id')
    ->leftJoin('jurors AS c', 'b.j_id', 'c.id')
    ->leftJoin('accommodations AS d', 'c.id', 'd.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('employment AS e', 'c.id', 'e.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('excuses AS f', 'c.id', 'f.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('new_address AS g', 'c.id', 'g.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('spouse AS h', 'c.id', 'h.juror_id')
    ->leftJoin('travel AS i', 'c.id', 'i.juror_id')
    ->where('a.id', 1)
    ->groupBy('c.id');

// dd($query->toRawSql());
$results = $query->get();

Perhaps one of the aliases was the issue?

Bogdan already pointed this out. Testing indicates this is not what's causing the concatenated data to repeat.

Tested your suggestion. Makes no difference. The GROUP_CONCAT() values repeat once for each value in the 1 to many joins in Laravel. The straight MySQL query returns GROUP_CONCAT() values (strings) that do not repeat.

My suggestion was that you make sure the queries ran are identical by using $query->toSql()

I understood you. I down-voted your answer because it's basically the same as Bogdan's
